# js function with variables for re-use

Tags: javascript

For js, I have following function:

```
function custom(){
 var rhcmm_append = function (data) {       
    var id    =  data.ids;
    var name  =  data.names;
    // and more variables and conditions etc
 };
 ...
}
```

I have few occasions in which I use the same variables and functions inside of `function(data)`.

Is there a way to make these variables into a function that I can re-use?

For example:

```
 function VAR_FUNCTION(data){
    var rin_ids         =  data.thread_id.split(',');
    var rin_user        =  data.user_name;  
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain more what you're looking for? Not sure I fully understand.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by re-use? you can simply assign new properties to an upper context variables from your `VAR_FUNCTION`

Comment: don't get it, what you are asking for. kind of default-values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't get exactly what you are asking for, however, I guess you would need something like this:

```
function extractor(data){
    // further processing might be done here.
    // processing on 'data'
    return {
        id: data.id,
        name: data.name
    };
}
```

Then you can use this utility function where ever you need.

```
function custom(){
    var rhcmm_append = function (data) {       
        var pairs  =  extractor(data);

        // do stuff with 'pairs'
    };
...
}
```

Or

```
function VAR_FUNCTION(data){
    var pairs = extractor(data);
    // do stuff with 'pairs'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make these variables and functions global, limit their scope inside an anonymous function or use a global object that holds variables/functions, some examples:

```
// Global
var myVar = 'value';
function myFunction(){}



// Limit scope inside an anonymous function
(function(){
  var myVar = 'value';
  function myFunction(){}

  // To access variables/functions all your code needs to reside inside here
});



// Make a global object
var reusables = {
  myVar: 'value',
  myFunction: function(){}
};

// Example
reusables.myVar
reusables.myFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to re-use, you can create the global variable.